# Compactification of Betti Moduli space $M_B$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Context of the question: Let $G=\pi_1(S_g)$ be the fundamental group of the oriented closed surface of genus $g$. The $P=W$ conjecture states that a certain filtration (of algebraic geometric origin) on the cohomology of the Betti moduli space $M_B(r)$ of all $r$-dimensional complex representations of $G$ is equal to the weight filtration induced by its natural structure of affine variety.

The question. I think this weight filtration has to do with a 'compactification' of $M_B$ which would make it compact Kähler. But I have no idea how to compactify, and even if I had, how the cohomology of the compactification would relate to the original cohomology. I have tried looking up the literature but have found nothing much.

Could anybody give a reference for this sort of questions? Thank you very much.

Comment: ‘Mixed Hodge Structures’ is the key word for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. So indeed I see there’s a theorem by Deligne that every complex variety carries a filtration on the cohomology that goes by this name. I’m reading that this has to do with the cohom. of a certain completion (the paper says, by résolution of singularities? but here $M_B$ is already smooth), but I dont quite get what that may mean. Sorry if these  question are stupid or seem to show lazyness, it’s just I’m out of my depth here.

Comment: The Betti moduli space is an affine variety, as you said, but it is not proper, even though it's smooth. You will need to compactify it, i.e. find a proper smooth variety such that it has the Betti moduli space as an open dense subset inside it.

Comment: Yes, that's what I would like to understand, and also, how the compactification's cohmology then relates to the dense open's. Would you happen to know a place where this is explained?

Comment: I am not sure what your question is. First of all, there is no ~~*the*~~ compactification - there is no reason to believe that compactification gives you something unique.

Comment: For a concrete example, consider affine 2-space. It has two different compactifications, P^2 and P^1 x P^1. The former has Betti numbers $ b_0, b_2, b_4 $ equal to $ 1,1,1 $ while the latter has those as $ 1,2,1 $.

Comment: What is non-trivial is the fact that the Mixed Hodge Structure (MHS) on the cohomology of your original variety is independent of whatever compactification you choose. A compactification is just part of the process allowing you to get the weight filtration. You will find this in many books dealing with MHS.

Comment: Sure, I wrote ‘the’ assuming one compactification had been chosen.

Comment: Sorry that I havent been clear. My question is whether there is an easy particular compactification in the case of $M_B$ which would put a MHS structure on $H^\ast(M_B)$ without having to resort to the big theory. My reason for hoping there is are 1/ Moduli spaces generally have meaningful compactifications, such as in the case of curves, etc. 2/ the corresponding (diffeomorphic as per Simpson) moduli space of Higgs bundle $M_{Dol}$ does have an easily constructed compactification.

Comment: by the way thank you for your time this has already been very helpful.

Comment: You are welcome, however the extent of my knowledge stops there - I don't know how to compactify the moduli space. I've been in a few talks by Davesh Maulik on this subject and I think Hausel found out the MHS on the Betti moduli space.